# Formatting multiple USB sticks in Linux

Tags: bash, debian

I'm trying to write a program in bash to format 7 usb sticks at once and create a new partition for each usb stick. The problem is the usb sticks are varying makes and models and sizes and so I also need to find the size of the available space on the stick and then create a partition that is that size.

Comment: Do you really need to create a partition on every device and not just use the whole device as one filesystem?

Comment: Yeah , we are going to be reusing the usb sticks so we need to format them,create a new partition so they can be reused

Comment: What I actually mean is by default an external device could be accessed as a whole as /dev/sdc and partitions generated could be /dev/sdc1, /dev/sdc2 etc. You could actually just create the filesystem just for /dev/sdc like mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc, not needing to create /dev/sdc1 and do mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1. What filesystem do you need by the way? Ext4? VFat?

Comment: Btw, /dev/sdc is just an example. It depends on your drive.

Comment: Fat16 is the filesystem we need

Answer (score 0):

This one could create filesystems but still doesn't partition them before creating. Save this to a script like script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND=("mkfs.ext4" "-option1" "-option2")  ## Change this depending on the formatting tool you'll use.

for DEV; do
    echo "Creating a filesystem for $D."
    read -p "Continue? " && [[ $REPLY == [yY] ]] || break  ## You could remove this line if you don't want to confirm.
    "${COMMAND[@]}" "$DEV"
done
```

And run it with `bash script.sh /dev/yourdevice1 [/dev/yourdevice2]`

Example:

`bash script.sh /dev/sdc /dev/sdd1`

Be careful and check your arguments before running the script.

Comment: I like this answer but for the volume of disks we are going to be processing (200 a week) I do need something that is just plug+go rather than typing in individual devices